# Adding RVM on production server with existing version of Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I have a server running an antiquated Ruby 1.8.6 that was the default with Ubuntu 8.04 and I need to upgrade to 1.8.7.  I'm thinking RVM is the best option for this, but I'm wondering if there are any pitfall with migrating everything over to this new version.  For example, if I set rvm to be the default for when I open a new console, how do I use the previously installed version of Ruby to stop my thin servers?  Anything else I should be cautious about?

Answer (score 0):

This is a reasonable way to do it. You could use something like rvm wrapper to create a new thin executable which fires up the correct RVM:

```
$ rvm wrapper your_ruby@your_gemset your_app_name thin
$ you_app_name_thin start
```

FWIW, There's also ruby-build, which provides less of a solution to the problem of managing multiple rubies and multiple projects on the same machine. But, one could argue that this "less of a solution" is actually "enough of a solution"). With ruby-build you might be able to directly refer to the full path to your thin installation, instead of creating a wrapper script.

*Update*: or you could use RVM shell, as I describe in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048050/rvm-running-user-scripts/8050900#8050900).