# RVM on Ruby Scripts

Tags: ruby, scripting, rvm

I need for a Ruby script to be run using an rvm-selected version. I cannot change how the script is invoked, but I can modify the script. The script starts with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Now, based on some information I found (in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048050/rvm-running-user-scripts), for example), I tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env rvm-shell ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gitorious
```

But this only gives me this error message:

```
/usr/bin/env: rvm-shell ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gitorious: No such file or directory
```

Now, `rvm` is available, because this works (but doesn't bring the required ruby/gemset):

```
#!/usr/bin/env rvm-shell
```

I've tried this as well:

```
#!/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gitorious
```

But this doesn't bring in the environment ("gem", which is only installed inside that gemset, is not available, for example). If I run that on the command line itself, it does open a shell with the proper environment.

So, has anyone done something like this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

`#!/location/of/rvm/folder/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gitorious/bin/ruby`

Comment: you are almost there, your trick will bring exact ruby, with `#!/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell ree-1.8.7-2012.02@gitorious` it should work better